# WordPress Shortcode - Get post data by ID

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I've created a post type name "Gallery" and added some post meta boxes to it. For now, let's say there is a Title and a Content for each single gallery.

now, I want to make a use of that data with Shortcode. How Is this possible?

For example -
**[gallery id=x]**

I know how to take the value of ID (**x**), but how do I output a post with the ID of that value?

I register this shortcode like so (but of course it's not completed)

```
function shortcote_gallery( $atts , $content = null ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'title' => 'Default Gallery Title'
        ), $
    return "<h3>$title</h3><p>$content</p>";
}
add_shortcode( 'gallery', 'shortcote_gallery' );
```

I hope I was clear enough. If not, please let me know so I explain myself better.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need of this function? Or I haven't understood your question.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post

Enjoy your code!

Comment: This is indeed the solution, Thank you very much. I'm sorry I can't upvote this :(.

Comment: You are welcome :) If it's the solution flag this as win. Bye

Answer (score 1):

In your example:

`[gallery id=x]`
has as parameter the field `id`.

So in your shortcode-function, you need to extract that as well.

```php
function shortcote_gallery( $atts , $content = null ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'title' => 'Default Gallery Title',
            'id' => '',
        ), $atts));
    return "<h3>$title</h3><p>$content</p>";
}
```

You now can do everything you want in the usual php way. `$id` now has the value you entered in your post. So if you want to output something with this ID, just fire a query to the database and fetch the results you need.

If you have something like this:

```
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `myTable` WHERE id ='".$id."'");
```

Here you go and format the output:

```
$content = "You have selected ".$results[0]->myField." with the id: $id";
return $content;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. It's exactly what I'm trying to do and I know for certain this would work. But I'm not sure if get_results is safe enough to use. Is this the only way to "pull" a post by ID? Thank you again.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about this, but you can (and you should) do some validation for the variables. For example, cast the id to an int (or check if it is an int). If you use the built-in functions, you should put trust in the framework. 

You can access your DB without that "get_results"-thingy and do a normal sql-query with `mysql_real_escape_string()` or something. For that purpose, I'd totally do it with the DB